# How to remove the Tab top title on iOS?

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I have a tab group with two tabs. The tab name is being displayed two times, one under the tab icon on the bottom and one on the top of the app just under the status bar.

I want to remove the top tab title on iOS.

[image: This is a sample screen.]

Thanks.

Regards

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I will just try to look into other ways of implementing a menu in iOS. Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `navBarHidden:true` to your Window inside the tab to remove the navigation bar.

Comment: Hello, i need the NavBar. I'm using this https://github.com/viezel/NappSlideMenu . I want to remove just the title on top. Also when i try your way, the title is still there and the Nav button only disappears  . There seems to be another bar on top of the nav bar.

Comment: you mean just the title text (so `required` in your image)? Just don't set the `title` property. If you can just add some code to your question.

Comment: Miga, just the top title. I want to leave the one under the tabs icons.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want the navbar to remain, and don't want a title. Don't set one! By default there is no title on the window, and window title and tabbar title are separate! This is how it should look after:

```
<TabGroup>
  <Tab title="required">
    <Window></Window>
  </Tab>
</TabGroup>
```

Same structure can be applied when you use classic.

If you want to remove the title at some point instead of always, you can just call `window.title = "";` and it will be removed. Of course replace "window" with the variable or alloy id (in which case it is `$.id`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bro, I will try your advice and report back.

Comment: I'm using `<TabGroup><Tab><NavigationWindow><Window></Window></NavigationWindow></Tab></TabGroup>` .   I'm using github.com/viezel/NappSlideMenu .  I'm not sure if its the problem.

Comment: The tab number Two is not displaying the title on top. and is working normally. only the one with the <NavigationWindow> . The screenshot is not the real app. It is just to give an idea of the issue. The app has <NavigationWindows> and uses the NappSlideMenu Widget.

Comment: why post a different screenshot when this doesn't help finding the solution but leads us in the wrong direction. If nothing changed this ticket https://github.com/viezel/NappSlideMenu/issues/36 says that it is not possible what you are trying to do. In my app I fake the TabGroup and create a custom ScrollableView with a bottom navigation. Then you have full control over the navigationWindow and can use NappSlideMenu without a problem. With NappDrawer it looks like you can add the TabGroup as a center view: https://github.com/viezel/NappDrawer/issues/150

Comment: @Miga, thanks for the reply. Do you think that i should use the NappDrawer ? i only want a simple menu for my iOS app with links to open a window for each option.

Comment: one advantage: it is a crossplatform widget in case you need an Android version too. As stated above: I'm using a scrollableView with a custom view at the bottom, slidemenu for ios, native drawerlayout for android, custom hamburger items. Not real native behaviour but full control over the bottom navigation buttons (e.g. custom notification bubbles over icons, custom colors,...)

Comment: to get back to this, you cannot nest NavigationWindow in a Tab. a tab itself is already a navigationwindow!